# Stepper motor noise

Tags: noise, grounding, stepper-motor, ground-loop

I’m currently developing a belt drive system that uses two separate Nema 42 stepper motors and an htd pulley. Everything is working well except I recently increased the supply voltage from 110 to 220 (single phase not split phase) in order to take advantage of the motors torque capability.  Doing so has amplified a noticeable audible noise in the motors at rest that sound like a rough clicking or chatter and can cause the motors to have choppy motion when driving.

The motors are Nema 42 3 phase open loop motors using an appropriate driver supplied by the same company who sold the motors. The drivers takes 110 to 220 directly from the wall, so I have one for each motor both connected to the same wall plug.  There are three motor wires plus a ground wire that is connected to the motor housing. I’ve isolated the issue to likely be grounding related:

- The noise is present even when disconnecting any low voltage signals (micro controller).
- The noise is not present if I simply don’t connect the grounds back to each driver and the motors are isolated
- The noise is present if the motors grounds are connected, even if not back to the drivers. This is noticeable when they are both mounted to the metal frame they bolt on to.
- If the motors are isolated and only one motor is connected to ground, the opposite motor is noisy but the one connected to ground is not.
- Here’s the fun one - there is some really noticeable leakage to ground. Without connecting motor ground back to the driver I measure 190V AC and 150mA.

I can’t find much documentation or other challenges with multiple 3 phase stepper motors online, not sure if I can resolve this with some sort of passive or active filter on the ground lines or if there is something wrong with the motors themselves. Appreciate any guidance as I’ve exhausted all of the troubleshooting I feel capable of!

Comment: Not terribly surprising but adding a ferrite bead to each ground wire noticeably decreases the noise.  Seemed to perform well with 3 loops through the bead.  I might be able to make that work if I insulate the motor mounts but something still seems generally wrong.

Comment: Are your steppers setup to stay at 100% holding torque when not moving?  Can you mitigate the issue by reducing the holding/standby current (if your system allows)?  Adding a bead to your ground seems like an undesirable choice.  Is there a slew-rate adjustment for your stepper waveforms (or maybe max frequency) that you can try reducing?  Shielded cables?  Cables properly sized?